# MongoDB sliding window aggregations

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

Imagine i have set a 5 minute time window.I want to have 5 sec sliding windows within the 5 minute window i have already set and move every second in order to check some data.For example,i have set the time window from 00:00:00-00:05:00. What i want to achieve is within that 5 min span to have a sliding window that goes like this 00:00:00-00:00:05 then 00:00:01-00:00:06 then 00:00:02-00:00:07 and so on until the 00:05:00.I have tried everything but i cannot solve this.Can somebody help?
Sorry for my english i am not a native speaker.
The objects have timestamp if that can help.

i have tried this

```
windowStart: {
      $subtract: [
        "$raised",
        {
          $dateFromParts: {
            year: { $year: "$raised" },
            month: { $month: "$raised" },
            day: { $dayOfMonth: "$raised" },
            hour: { $hour: "$raised" },
            minute: { $minute: "$raised" },
            second: { $subtract: [{ $second: "$raised" }, { $mod: [{ $second: "$raised" }, 5] }] },
            millisecond: 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but i does not work at all.

Comment: Sliding window for which calculation? Please provide sample documents and the requested result for them